# How to create FTP drop directory on an Azure website (app service)

Tags: azure, ftp

Trying to migrate a website to Azure at the moment.

We have a daily upload to the current website that is sent by FTP.

How do you do this (or similar - should I be dropping the files in a BLOB and reading from there?) in Azure?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can upload to Azure app service (previously website) with the FTP (FTP over TLS/SSL specifically) too.

On your web site dashboard on Azure Management Portal see the *FTPS hostname*. And in the *Deployment Center*, setup your FTP credentials.

For details, see (my) article [Connecting to an (Azure) App Service (Web Site) with FTPS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure#appservice).